# Why does instanceof return false for some literals?

Tags: javascript, literals, instanceof

```
"foo" instanceof String //=> false
"foo" instanceof Object //=> false

true instanceof Boolean //=> false
true instanceof Object //=> false
false instanceof Boolean //=> false
false instanceof Object //=> false

12.21 instanceof Number //=> false
/foo/ instanceof RegExp //=> true

// the tests against Object really don't make sense
```

Array literals and Object literals match...

```
[0,1] instanceof Array //=> true
{0:1} instanceof Object //=> true
```

Why don't all of them? Or, why don't they all *not*?
And, what are they an instance of, then?

It's the same in FF3, IE7, Opera, and Chrome. So, at least it's consistent.

Answer (score 520, accepted):

Primitives are a different kind of type than objects created from within Javascript. From the [Mozilla API docs](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/instanceof_Operator):

```
var color1 = new String("green");
color1 instanceof String; // returns true
var color2 = "coral";
color2 instanceof String; // returns false (color2 is not a String object)
```

I can't find any way to construct primitive types with code, perhaps it's not possible. This is probably why people use `typeof "foo" === "string"` instead of `instanceof`.

An easy way to remember things like this is asking yourself "I wonder what would be sane and easy to learn"? Whatever the answer is, Javascript does the other thing.

Comment: That's true of string literals but not of all literals, such as object, function or array literals. Another reason for the `typeof` check rather than `instanceof` is that the `typeof` test will still work on strings from other frames or windows, or in a (admittedly contrived) situation where the `String` constructor has been overwritten.

Comment: you can turn String object into string literal like type using + ''. (new String('green') + '') instanceof String // returns false

Comment: the same also works for Number with +0, Boolean with & true, regexes are a bit special as they differ too much across browsers...

Comment: Every day with a new reason to hate JavaScript is a good day. I know it's long overdue but I thank you for this post.

Comment: Your terminology is wrong. The word "literal" refers to a syntax for creating data without using a constructor. It doesn't refer to the resulting data. Literal syntax can be used to create both objects and non-objects. The correct term is "primitives", which refer to non-object data. Some data has both primitive and object representations. String is one of those types of data.

Comment: FYI, you can create primitives without literal syntax. `(new String()).valueOf();`

Comment: Note that `typeof foo === 'string'` is not enough:  see axkibe's answer.

Comment: JSON.parse returns primitives too - `JSON.parse('"foo"') instanceof String` <-- false

Comment: or you can use Object.prototype.toString.call(foo)

Comment: Yet another sign that JS is inconsistent and confusing by design. Why a literal should be a different animal?Why no one cares to fixe it? Maybe it's fixed in ES6?

Comment: @NaderHadjiGhanbari - This isn't about *literals* being different, it's about *primitive* values being different. The fact that the string was created with a literal is irrelevant, it could as easily have been the return value from `.replace()`, `.charAt()`, `.join()`, `JSON.stringify()`, etc.

Comment: In additional, `typeof new String('')` returns `"object"`

Answer (score 127):

I use:

```
function isString(s) {
    return typeof(s) === 'string' || s instanceof String;
}
```

Because in JavaScript strings can be literals or objects.

Comment: I found something shorte btw. `function isString(s) { return s.constructor === String; }` Works for literals and string objects (at least in V8)

Comment: I use jQuery.type(s) === 'string' (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.type/), jQuery.isArray(), jQuery.isFunction(), jQuery.isNumeric() when it's possible.

Comment: @axkibe while you're correct, it's [not nearly as performant](http://jsperf.com/typeof-vs-constructor) as `typeof`.

Comment: You can use typeof "?" == String.name.toLowerCase() [but why is [] instanceof Array ?]

Comment: Same problem exists for Boolean values: `true instanceof Boolean => false` and yet `typeof true => boolean` ... What even. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4745303/362042

Comment: I use `function isString(s) { return {}.toString.call(s) === "[object String]"; }` which is a null-tolerant function that works for both instances and literals

Comment: @QuentinUK because `"?"` is a **primitive and literal** value of `String`. `String`, `Number` and `Boolean` are primitive constructors, the literal default values of that primitive constructors are respectively represented as:
`''` for `String`; _(`"?"` is a literal of `String` too)_
`0` for `Number`;
`false` for `Boolean`.

While *`[]`* and `{}` are **non-primitive literals** for *`Array`* and `Object` constructors respectively!

If you have a **primitive literal**, you should use `typeof`.

If you have a **non-primitive literal** you can use `instanceof`, since it's more performant!

Comment: @QuentinUK See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6625960/6399857)

Comment: I just learned about this and was surprised by it because I've always just used `typeof x === "string"`. Where are string object instances ever found in the wild? Do people really use `new String("foo")` ?

Answer (score 77):

In JavaScript everything is an object (or may at least be treated as an object), except [primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) (booleans, null, numbers, strings and the value `undefined` (and symbol in ES6)):

```
console.log(typeof true);           // boolean
console.log(typeof 0);              // number
console.log(typeof "");             // string
console.log(typeof undefined);      // undefined
console.log(typeof null);           // object
console.log(typeof []);             // object
console.log(typeof {});             // object
console.log(typeof function () {}); // function
```

As you can see objects, arrays and the value `null` are all considered objects (`null` is a reference to an object which doesn't exist). Functions are distinguished because they are a special type of *callable* objects. However they are still objects.

On the other hand the literals `true`, `0`, `""` and `undefined` are not objects. They are primitive values in JavaScript. However booleans, numbers and strings also have constructors `Boolean`, `Number` and `String` respectively which wrap their respective primitives to provide added functionality:

```
console.log(typeof new Boolean(true)); // object
console.log(typeof new Number(0));     // object
console.log(typeof new String(""));    // object
```

As you can see when primitive values are wrapped within the `Boolean`, `Number` and `String` constructors respectively they become objects. The `instanceof` operator only works for objects (which is why it returns `false` for primitive values):

```
console.log(true instanceof Boolean);              // false
console.log(0 instanceof Number);                  // false
console.log("" instanceof String);                 // false
console.log(new Boolean(true) instanceof Boolean); // true
console.log(new Number(0) instanceof Number);      // true
console.log(new String("") instanceof String);     // true
```

As you can see both `typeof` and `instanceof` are insufficient to test whether a value is a boolean, a number or a string - `typeof` only works for primitive booleans, numbers and strings; and `instanceof` doesn't work for primitive booleans, numbers and strings.

Fortunately there's a simple solution to this problem. The default implementation of `toString` (i.e. as it's natively defined on `Object.prototype.toString`) returns the internal `[[Class]]` property of both primitive values and objects:

```
function classOf(value) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(value);
}

console.log(classOf(true));              // [object Boolean]
console.log(classOf(0));                 // [object Number]
console.log(classOf(""));                // [object String]
console.log(classOf(new Boolean(true))); // [object Boolean]
console.log(classOf(new Number(0)));     // [object Number]
console.log(classOf(new String("")));    // [object String]
```

The internal `[[Class]]` property of a value is much more useful than the `typeof` the value. We can use `Object.prototype.toString` to create our own (more useful) version of the `typeof` operator as follows:

```
function typeOf(value) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(value).slice(8, -1);
}

console.log(typeOf(true));              // Boolean
console.log(typeOf(0));                 // Number
console.log(typeOf(""));                // String
console.log(typeOf(new Boolean(true))); // Boolean
console.log(typeOf(new Number(0)));     // Number
console.log(typeOf(new String("")));    // String
```

Hope this article helped. To know more about the differences between primitives and wrapped objects read the following blog post: [The Secret Life of JavaScript Primitives](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/the-secret-life-of-javascript-primitives/)

Comment: +1, altough `null` is a [primitive value](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.2) as well (only the `typeof` operator is confusing)

Answer (score 43):

You can use constructor property:

```
'foo'.constructor == String // returns true
true.constructor == Boolean // returns true
```

Comment: Note that when testing variables this technique can fail in certain circumstances. There is an implicit reference to the current window in front of `String` and `Boolean` in the above example, so if you are testing the `constructor` property of a string variable created in another window (like a popup or frame) it will _not_ be equal to simply `String`, it will be equal to `thatOtherWindowsName.String`.

Comment: And doesn't instanceof deal with this and return the appropriate boolean result?

Comment: this fails if you're passed a descendant of String.

Comment: @MichaelMathews: This works to remedy that: `Object.prototype.toString.call('foo') === '[object String]'`

Comment: @BryanLarsen and @MichaelMathews Is there any issue in using `d.constructor == String`? E.g. with a loose equality operator.

Answer (score 18):

```
 typeof(text) === 'string' || text instanceof String;
```

you can use this, it will work for both case as

1. `var text="foo";`  // typeof will work
2. `String text= new String("foo");`  // instanceof will work

Comment: I have been surprised to learn about this. Do people really use instances of String objects in the wild?

Answer (score 3):

This is defined in the ECMAScript specification [Section 7.3.19 Step 3](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinaryhasinstance): `If Type(O) is not Object, return false.`

In other word, if the `Obj` in `Obj instanceof Callable` is not an object, the `instanceof` will short-circuit to `false` directly.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have come up with a viable solution:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf('test') === String.prototype    //true
Object.getPrototypeOf(1) === String.prototype         //false
```

Answer (score 2):

The primitive wrapper types are reference types that are automatically created behind the scenes whenever strings, num­bers, or Booleans
are read.For example :

```
var name = "foo";
var firstChar = name.charAt(0);
console.log(firstChar);
```

This is what happens behind the scenes:

```
// what the JavaScript engine does
var name = "foo";
var temp = new String(name);
var firstChar = temp.charAt(0);
temp = null;
console.log(firstChar);
```

Because the second line uses a string (a primitive) like an object,
the JavaScript engine creates an instance of String so that charAt(0) will
work.The String object exists only for one statement before it’s destroyed
check [this](https://dev.to/benjaminmock/do-you-know-what-autoboxing-in-js-is-enl)

The **instanceof** operator returns false because a temporary object is
created only when a value is read. Because instanceof doesn’t actually read
anything, no temporary objects are created, and it tells us the ­values aren’t
instances of primitive wrapper types. You can create primitive wrapper
types manually

Answer (score 0):

I did check `instanceof` of value by checking the `constructor` of it like this :

```
const checkIsInstanceOf = (value, instance) => value.constructor === instance;

console.log(checkIsInstanceOf(5, Number)); // true
console.log(checkIsInstanceOf(5, String)); // false
console.log(checkIsInstanceOf(new Date(), Function)); // false
console.log(checkIsInstanceOf("Reza", String)); // true
```

Answer (score -2):

For me the confusion caused by

```
"str".__proto__ // #1
=> String
```

So `"str" istanceof String` should return `true` because how istanceof works as below:

```
"str".__proto__ == String.prototype // #2
=> true
```

Results of expression **#1** and **#2** conflict each other, so there should be one of them wrong.

**#1 is wrong**

I figure out that it caused by the `__proto__` is non standard property, so use the standard one:`Object.getPrototypeOf`

```
Object.getPrototypeOf("str") // #3
=> TypeError: Object.getPrototypeOf called on non-object
```

Now there's no confusion between expression **#2** and **#3**

Comment: #1 is correct, but it's due to the [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), which boxes the primitive value to its respective object type, similar to `Object("str").__proto__` or `Object("str") instanceof String`.

Answer (score -9):

Or you can just make your own function like so:

```
function isInstanceOf(obj, clazz){
  return (obj instanceof eval("("+clazz+")")) || (typeof obj == clazz.toLowerCase());
};
```

usage:

```
isInstanceOf('','String');
isInstanceOf(new String(), 'String');
```

These should both return true.