# Property value of a String object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

As far as I understand, every string is an object in Javascript. Still, it "does not work" as I expect it to be:

```
var a="abc";  //here we get a new string object
a.b = 123;    //I seem to declare a property "b" of that object
alert(a.b);   //alerts "undefined"
```

However, if I try to define a string in the "wrong way", everything works as expected

```
var a=new String("abc"); //
a.b = 123;
alert(a.b);    //alerts "123"
```

Why is that so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because the [property accessors](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.2.1), (`.` and `[]`) convert the value [ToObject](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-9.9).

Something equivalent to this happens behind the scenes:

```
var a="abc";
new Object(a).b = 123;  
alert(a.b); // undefined
```

Basically an object is created on the fly, by the property accessor, see the Step 5:

The production `MemberExpression` : `MemberExpression [ Expression ]` (or `MemberExpression . Identifier`) is evaluated as follows:

1. Evaluate `MemberExpression`.
2. Call `GetValue(Result(1))`.
3. Evaluate Expression.
4. Call `GetValue(Result(3))`.
5. Call `ToObject(Result(2))`.
6. Call `ToString(Result(4))`.
7. Return a value of type Reference whose base object is Result(5) and whose property name is `Result(6)`.

Answer (score 8):

You may be interested in checking out the first part of this article:

- [The Complete Javascript Strings Reference](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Complete_Javascript_Strings_Reference)

Quoting:

> There are two different types of Strings and the behave quite differently. A literal is created just by using quotes around your string. An object is created by implicit use of the new keyword. If you assign a string to a variable using the String keyword, without the new keyword the contents of the parenthesis will be cast as a string literal.
>
> A string literal has access to all of a string's objects and methods because javascript will temporarily cast a string literal as a string object in order to run the desired method.
>
> Where the two differ is their treatment of new properties and methods. Like all Javascript Objects you can assign properties and methods to any String object.
>
> You can not add properties or methods to a string literal. They are ignored by the interpreter.
>
> The reason you can't add properties or methods to a string literal is that when you try to access a literal's property or method, the Javascript interpreter temporarily copies the value of the string into a new object and then use that object's properties or methods. This means a String literal can only access a string's default properties or methods and those that have been added as prototypes.

Comment: Got it, thanks - "The reason you can't add properties or methods to a string literal is that when you try to access a literal's property or method, the Javascript interpreter temporarily copies the value of the string into a new object and then use that object's properties or methods." ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is also interesting reading... [Are string literals objects or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018070/are-string-literals-objects-or-not)