# a String.prototype's "this" doesn't return a string?

Tags: javascript

What is going on here? Just when I thought I knew JS inside and out, this gem comes up.

```
String.prototype.doNothing = function() {
  return this;
};

alert(typeof 'foo'.doNothing()) // object
alert(typeof 'foo')             // string
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dJBmf/

This is breaking some things that expect a string, such as jQuery's `.text(str)` method.

Comment: use `this.valueOf()` and you should be OK , this should work globally no matter what mode you are in. @Bob's answer answers the problem cause enaugh :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Here's a thorough overview](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/) of the `this` keyword. Basically, JavaScript converts it into an object, if it wasn't one.

> The following steps are performed when
>   control enters the execution context
>   for function code contained in
>   function object F, a caller provided
>   thisValue, and a caller provided
>   argumentsList:
>
> 1. If the function code is strict code, set the ThisBinding to
>      thisValue.
> 2. Else if thisValue is null or undefined, set the ThisBinding to the
>      global object.
> 3. **Else if Type(thisValue) is not Object, set the ThisBinding to
>      ToObject(thisValue).**
> 4. Else set the ThisBinding to thisValue

Same thing happens to Numbers and Booleans. A similar `DoNothing` function would return a type of object.

Comment: String funny: Even though javascript Strings are actually objects, they are considered as basic types so they have their own type and are not considered as objects on the other hand Arrays are considered objects since they are not a basic type.

Answer (score 47):

To make sure you're always getting a string, trying using this code:

```
String.prototype.doNothing = function() {
    return this.toString();
};

alert(typeof 'foo'.doNothing())
alert(typeof 'foo')
```

In your original code, `this` is being returned as the string object and not the actual string.

Comment: That does the trick, thanks. Can you please elaborate or link to something that explains this behavior?

Comment: why not just return the `.valueOf()` string ? :)

Answer (score 7):

Run your code in `strict` mode to get your expected result!

Answer (score 1):

It's again the difference between string literals and strings, i believe? I once had a question answered here in SO: [Property value of a String object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739515/property-value-of-a-string-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You could've also used the `constructor` property:

```
'foo'.constructor === String; //=>true
'foo'.doNothing().constructor === String; //=>true
```

See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203739/why-does-instanceof-return-false-for-some-literals) and this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dJBmf/2/)

If `String.prototype.doNothing()` breaks stuff expecting a string value, I would use `return String(this)` or `this.toString()` (`this.valueOf()` also works here) indeed.

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
return this + '';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function print() {
  let str = this;
  console.log(str);
}

String.prototype.print = print;

let a = "hello";
 a.print();//output:"hello"
```

Answer (score -1):

To get a better understanding of what's going on try using console logs, like so:

```
String.prototype.doNothing = function() {
    console.log(this);
    return this;
};

console.log(typeof 'foo'.doNothing());
console.log(typeof 'foo');
```

These are the results I get in Firefox:

```
foo { 0="f", 1="o", more...}
object
string
```

So it seems in the prototype a string is represented as an object/an array of characters (which does make sense.)

Whether or not you should use toString (as suggested by McHerbie) or casting as a type String (as suggested by mellamokb) depends, in my opinion, on what you plan to do with this value. I would personally lean toward casting it as a String.

Comment: Yeah I saw the console thing, since the type is "object" firebug uses the "object inspection" output style. So this fools firebug as well...