# Javascript String Object V.S. just string

Tags: javascript, prototype

OK, first, i'm not going to seek a method to convert the `Object` to `String`.

but i'm facing a problem like this:

```
String.prototype.foo = function() {
    return this;
};

var rawString = "abcde";

var fooString = "abcde".foo();

console.log(typeof(rawString) + ': ', rawString);
console.log(typeof(fooString) + ': ', fooString);
```

or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GAWRc/) you preferred.

also, a screenshot is attached:

[image: the strange thing in Javascript.]

---

as you can see, i did almost nothing in the prototype method `foo`, i just `return this`.

but the result of `typeof` are totally different

Why is this? how can i just return `abcde` rather thant `{0: "a"...}` ?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript WTF: a String.prototype's "this" doesn't return a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146591/javascript-wtf-a-string-prototypes-this-doesnt-return-a-string)

Comment: @CrescentFresh oops, you're right. i tried to search, but i didn't make it. sorry for the duplicate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `this` references the `String Object`, so you need to return it like

```
return this.toString();
```

which in turn, creates the primitive string version and returns it.

Comment: great! thanks!! but feel so strange to write the `"string".toString()` .. LOL, odd javascript.

Comment: @bitsMix, it's an object oriented language