# Cannot get Javascript array "includes" to work in String prototype

Tags: javascript

The Javascript array "includes" function returns "false" when I used it in a String prototype, when I expected it to return "true" - any ideas why?

```
String.prototype.isIn = function (...constants) {
    var _this = this; //safety measure
    console.log("_this = " + _this);
    console.log("constants = " + constants);
    console.log("constants[1] = " + constants[1]);
    console.log("return value = " + constants.includes(_this));
    return constants.includes(_this);
}

console.log("'isIn' result = " + 'dog'.isIn('cat', 'dog', 'bat')); // why is this not "true"?

console.log("'includes' result = " + ['cat', 'dog', 'bat'].includes('dog')); // true, as expected
```

I have tried Chrome Version 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit) script editor, and nodejs v8.12.0

Comment: Switch your logging statements so they output the actual object and the problem becomes more apparent.  `console.log("_this = ", _this);` outputs `String {"dog"}`.  A `String` object is not equal to a plain old string literal.

Comment: Thank you - changing _this assignment  
     var _this = this.valueOf(); 
did the trick

Comment: Also, setting `'use strict'` works without using `valueOf()`, as described in [the referenced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146591/a-string-prototypes-this-doesnt-return-a-string). Weird - this seems less strict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/valueOf) of `this`, because `this` contains the prototype properties, but you need the primitive value for checking with `includes` (which checks strict).

```js
String.prototype.isIn = function (...constants) {
    return constants.includes(this.valueOf());
};

var pets = ['cat', 'dog', 'bat'];

console.log("'isIn' result = " + 'dog'.isIn('cat', 'dog', 'bat')); // why is this not "true"?
```

Comment: `toString` would also work - oh I see that's probably the same. I'd like to leave my [repl](https://repl.it/@alexanderwolf/Extending-stringprototype-with-isIn?language=javascript).