# Creating a method on a 2D array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, multidimensional-array

I've created a 2D array and interfaced with it quite a lot through my code, but when I try to do something like this:

```
worldmap[x][y].eventAct = function() { 
     State.updateState("WorldMap"); 
     console.log("Event called"); 
}
```

It doesn't work, however when I do this:

```
worldmap[x].eventAct = function() { 
     State.updateState("WorldMap"); 
     console.log("Event called"); 
}
```

It works, but it becomes useless as I don't know what x and y co-ords the event takes place, I only know the x!

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what exactly...is the issue?

Comment: When I do what I want, the first one, worldmap[x][y].eventAct = function() etc, and then I try to call it, even through the console it doesn't exist, whereas when I do the 2nd method with a standard array it works fine and the eventAct method is callable, if that makes any sense!

Comment: What is the value of `worldmap[x][y]`? Primitive values, such as from number or string literals, [can't really hold their own properties](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2739515).

Comment: The value of worldmap[x][y] in this case: x = 14, y = 23 and the actual value of what's stored there is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values in `worldmap` are all [primitive values](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.2), then they simply [can't hold properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2739515).

```
var foo = 'bar';
foo.baz = 'qux';
console.log(foo.baz); // undefined
```

The property can be set because primitives [can be boxed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_(object-oriented_programming)#Boxing) and treated as objects. But, the boxing doesn't persist, so the property is lost immediately after.

So, you could create the Object to hold the values and methods:

```
worldmap[x][y] = {
    value: worldmap[x][y],

    eventAct: function() {
        State.updateState("WorldMap");
        console.log("Event called");
    }
};
```

```
console.log(worldmap[x][y].value);
```

Or, similar to your 2nd snippet, you could attach the method to the arrays and accept the missing indices as arguments:

```
worldmap[x].eventAct = function (y) {
    var value = this[y];

    State.updateState("WorldMap"); 
    console.log("Event called");
};
```