# What is the value of "this" in "click" handler in KnockoutJS?

Tags: knockout.js

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/bigaq/1/edit)

Consider the following example:

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="with: job">
  <div data-bind="foreach: tasks">
    <div>
      <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
      <span data-bind="click: $parent.allDone">(Done)</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
ko.applyBindings(function() {
  this.job = {
    tasks: ['Buy milk', 'Sleep', 'Work', 'Praise'],
    allDone: function(data) {
      console.log(this);
      console.log(data);
    }
  };
});
```

Could you clarify the following points:

1. Why the value of `this` in `allDone` is not `job`? Isn't `allDone` called via `$parent` who is the `job`?
2. Is there a way to call `allDone` on click such that the value of `this` would be `job`?
3. The value of `this` and `data` seems similar, but not quite the same:

   `this -> String {0: "S", 1: "l", 2: "e", 3: "e", 4: "p", length: 5}`

   `data -> Sleep`

   What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `this` is operating under the scope of the `allDone` function, so it will not refer to `job`. `allDone` is being called via `$parent`, in this case the `job`, but that is in the data-binding syntax - that won't mean that your `this` in the Javascript will refer to `job`.
2. Yes, you can use set the value of `this` for the job to another variable. The common way to do it is to use `var self = this`. You can then refer to the parent object (`job`) via `self` within the scope of child functions. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwisch45/3yhxg/2/)

   ```
   var job = function () {
       var self = this;

       this.tasks = ['Buy milk', 'Sleep', 'Work', 'Praise'];
       this.allDone = function (data) {
           console.log(self); // refers to the parent job now
           console.log(data); // refers to the current item in the data-bound array
       };
   };

   ko.applyBindings(new job());
   ```
3. Your original `this` was treating the simple string as a `new Object(data)`.
   Using your original code,
   `new Object(data)` --> `String {0: "S", 1: "l", 2: "e", 3: "e", 4: "p", length: 5}`

   Refer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146591/javascript-wtf-a-string-prototypes-this-doesnt-return-a-string) for more details. Another post to reference is [this SO post on Property value of a String object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739515/property-value-of-a-string-object-in-javascript)