# "instanceof" of a String object vs that of "string" literals

Tags: javascript, inheritance, javascript-objects, instanceof, prototypal-inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does instanceof return false for some literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203739/why-does-instanceof-return-false-for-some-literals)

Does anyone know why x is not a instance of String/Object here?

```
var x = "abc",
y = new String("XYZ");

x instanceof String; // False
x instanceof Object; // False
y instanceof String; // True
(x.constructor === y.constructor) //True
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pCfWC/6/

Comment: Yep: http://stackoverflow.com/a/203757/15031 Asked a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/203739/15031) a while back. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203739/why-does-instanceof-return-false-for-some-literals