# How to "instanceof" a primitive string (string literal) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, instanceof, string-literals

In JavaScript, I can declare a string in the following ways;

```
var a = "Hello World";
var b = new String("Hello World");
```

but a is not an instance of String...

```
console.log(a instanceof String); //false;
console.log(b instanceof String); //true;
```

So how do you find the type or "`instanceof`" a string literal?

Can JavaScript be forced to create a `new String()` for every string literal?

Comment: to answer the actual question, in case you really like using `instanceof` (like me, and hate the `typeof ==` garbage) you can easily coerce things to objects when you check them. Whack this in your code `Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, '_object', {get:function() { return this; }});` and voila, `'string'._object instanceof String` returns `true`! You can avoid prototype and make functions if you want, but this makes for the most elegant if-statements

Comment: @Hashbrown This doesn't seem to work on strict mode. Is there any other way to use something like this when using strict mode?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

use `typeof "foo" === "string"` instead of `instanceof.`

Comment: excuse me, could you explain why?

Comment: @NinjaCoding basically you can check the link provided at the start of the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203739/why-does-instanceof-return-false-for-some-literals. You'll find a more detailed explanation. But essentially `String` objects are not primitives, that's the thing. Welcome to js =)

Comment: well that's not gonna work if it actually is a `String` (`(function() { return typeof this; }).call('foo')`: `object`), [this'll work for both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792051/how-to-instanceof-a-primitive-string-string-literal-in-javascript#comment89420815_16792051)

Comment: @NinjaCoding because this answers the first question "So how do you find the type or "instanceof" a string literal?"

Answer (score 13):

Use `typeof` instead and just compare the resulting string. See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the doc link; but [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) is just as pertinent: "The instanceof operator tests presence of constructor.prototype in object's prototype chain."

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to write `new String()` to create a new string. When we write `var x = 'test';` statement, it create the `x` as a string from a primitive data type. We can't attach the custom properties to this `x` as we do with object literal. ie. `x.custom = 'abc';` `x.custom` will give undefined value. Thus as per our need we need to create the object. `new String()` will create an object with `typeof()` Object and not string. We can add custom properties to this object.