# Compare JavaScript values of different type (not strings)?

Tags: javascript

How can I find all items in an array by matching a property and dealing with case insensitivity ONLY IF the values are strings?  I have no way to know what data type the property on the object will be.  Both the target value and property may be a date, string, number, etc.

I'm basically trying to protect the next developer from shooting himself in the foot:

```
function getItemsByKey(key, value, isCaseSensitive) {
    var result = [];
    (getAll() || []).forEach(function(item){
        if (!(!!isCaseSensitive)) {
            if (item[key] && item[key].toString().toLowerCase() == value.toString().toLowerCase()) { result.push(item); }
        } else {
            if (item[key] == value) { result.push(item); }
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

What happens if they pass in `isCaseSensitive = true` and the values end up being dates or numbers... or mismatched?

Comment: `if (!(!!isCaseSensitive))` what the... this can be reduced to `if (!isCaseSensitive)`

Comment: I don't understand what this function is trying to accomplish. Why would you want to add isCaseSensitive to a key retrieval?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to "instanceof" a primitive string (string literal) in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792051/how-to-instanceof-a-primitive-string-string-literal-in-javascript)

Comment: Anyway, you can check if value is a string using typeof: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059147/check-if-a-variable-is-a-string

Comment: Are you trying to find items in an array, e.g. `['value1', 'value2']` or an object, e.g. `{ 'value1': 'hello', 'value2': 'hi' }`?

Comment: @VladFr : There is now way to know what type of objects `getAll()` will return.  It is meant to be a helper / utility function on a cache.

Comment: @VladFr : I'm trying to return all objects where a certain property might be matched.  For example `fruit == 'apple'` or 'count == 42`.

Comment: Regardless of the solution to this problem, it's highly recommended to use strong-typed comparison in js (`===` instead of `==`)...

Comment: @JanChimiak : I won't have any way to know what type of objects will be returned by `getAll()` nor if the target property will be the expected type.  The goal of using `toString()` was to reduce the properties to a common type.

Comment: I've posted the complete service on CodeReview: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/120914/member-specific-object-cache-for-angular

Answer (score 2):

See inline comment.

```
function getItemsByKey(key, value, isCaseSensitive) {
    var result = [];
    (getAll() || []).forEach(function(item){
        // Either the values are equal OR (not case sensitive AND item[key] and value are strings AND non-case sensitive match)
        if (item[key] == value || (
          !isCaseSensitive &&
          typeof item[key] == 'string' &&
          typeof value == 'string' &&
          item[key].toLowerCase() == value.toLowerCase())
        ) {
            result.push(item);
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: What would happen if one value was a number and the other a string?  Or one a date and the other a number?  Could they still be compared?

Comment: I've posted the complete service on CodeReview: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/120914/member-specific-object-cache-for-angular

Comment: In this case, I forced both to be strings.  If you want to use JS type coercion for equality (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators)) then you could say `(typeof item[key] == 'string' || typeof value == 'string)` which only requires one of the compared values to be a string.

Comment: You can also compare `item[key].toString().toLowerCase() == value.toString().toLowerCase()` like you have in your question.  You may want to use `"" + arg` instead of `toString()` to get around corner cases like `undefined` or primitives (i.e. `1` as opposed to `Number(1)` although this won't come up in a function invocation).