# What's the difference between using instanceof and checking the constructor?

Tags: javascript

Why do the following two lines return different results?

```
("test" instanceof String) // returns false
("test".constructor == String) // returns true
```

Tested in the console of chrome version 28.0.1500.95 m

Does it work slightly differently for native types?

Comment: i don't think it's a duplicate. it's actually a more general question.

Comment: @basilikum I agree. In addition I think the answers to the possibly duplicate question itself are insufficiently descriptive. I vote to reopen this question.

Comment: For what it's worth read the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18057157/783743

Comment: Your answer is interesting thanks, `native types have a constructor wrapper` is the explanation to the above. It's also useful to know that you can initialize those wrapper types with the first parameter as the primitive value.

Comment: @Ally i think the explanation is  when you write `"test"` it actually does `String("test");` and you get a primitive (so instanceof won't work because it's not an object). But when you try to use a literal as an object, the browsers convert it to a `String` object, that's why `.constructor` property appears.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation that makes it much easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: @meze is right. Autoboxing is the reason.

Comment: related, if not duplicate: [JavaScript inheritance and the constructor property](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8093057/1048572)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`constructor` is just a property of the internal `[[prototype]]` property, that can easily be manipulated:

```
function A(){}
function B(){}
A.prototype.constructor = B;

var a = new A();

console.log(a.constructor); //B
```

The `instanceof` operator however checks the internal prototype chain and is not so easily to be fooled, even if you change the complete `prototype` property of the constructor function:

```
function A(){}
function B(){}
A.prototype = B.prototype;

var a = new A();

console.log(a instanceof A); //true
console.log(a instanceof B); //false
```

---

So, why is `"test" instanceof String === false` but `("test".constructor == String) === true`?

First of all, `"test"` is a primitive and primitives are never an instance of anything. What actually happens when you use `instanceof` is that the internal `[[HasInstance]]` method of the constructor is called with the possible instance as an argument. So `a instanceof A` translates roughly to:

```
`A.[[HasInstance]](a)`
```

The ECMA Specs have this to say to `[[HasInstance]]`: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.5.3

> **[[HasInstance]] (V)**
>
> Assume F is a Function object.
>
> When the [[HasInstance]] internal method of F is called with value V,
>   the following steps are taken:
>
> > 1. If V is not an object, return false.
> > 2. ....

In other words: If the left hand side of `instanceof` is not an object, the operator will return false.

`("test".constructor == String) === true` works for a different reason: If you try to access a property of a primitive, the primitive will be temporarily converted into an object. So `"test".constructor` is roughly equal to:

```
(new String("test")).constructor
```

in which case you are actually creating an object, with a constructor function and requesting the `constructor` property afterward. So it is no surprise, that it will return `String`.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that `instanceof` inspects the object's prototype chain whereas checking the constructor only checks to see if it was created from the same constructor.

Example:

```
function MyObject() {
    this.sayHi = function() { alert('Hi!'); }   
}

var x = new MyObject();
alert(x.constructor === Object);
alert(x instanceof Object);
```