# isArray equivalent for new Map()?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I determine that my data structure is of type Map()?

I've been looking everywhere, and can't find any method

I really want to get into using them because I can use objects as keys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the **[instanceof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449254/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-in-javascript)** opeartor

```js
var map = new Map();
var arr = [];

console.log(map instanceof Map);
console.log(map instanceof Array);
console.log(arr instanceof Map);
console.log(arr instanceof Array);
```

From the [**Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

> The instanceof operator tests whether an object has in its prototype
>   chain the prototype property of a constructor.

Comment: Also, be aware of [the difference between `Array.isArray` and `instanceof Array`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289727/difference-between-using-array-isarray-and-instanceof-array).

Comment: @Pavlo Thanks for the useful link

Answer (score 3):

You could use either [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator or the [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) property and check against the object.

For more information read this: [What's the difference between using instanceof and checking the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055980/whats-the-difference-between-using-instanceof-and-checking-the-constructor)

```js
var map = new Map();
var arr = [];

console.log(map instanceof Map);         // true
console.log(map instanceof Array);       // false
console.log(map.constructor === Map);    // true
console.log(map.constructor === Array);  // false

console.log(arr instanceof Map);         // false
console.log(arr instanceof Array);       // true
console.log(arr.constructor === Map);    // false
console.log(arr.constructor === Array);  // true

// caveat!
console.log(arr.constructor === Object); // false
console.log(map.constructor === Object); // false
console.log(arr instanceof Object);      // true
console.log(map instanceof Object);      // true
```

Comment: A useful reference link: [instanceof vs constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055980/whats-the-difference-between-using-instanceof-and-checking-the-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

You can even use `Object.prototype.toString.call`, though `instanceof`(@[suren srapyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5496973/suren-srapyan)'s answer) is more preferred

```js
var a = [1,2,3];
var m = new Map()
a.forEach((x,i)=>m.set(i+1, x));

console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(m))
```