# typeof and instanceof operators returns different information for the same var

Tags: javascript

Observe the following lines of JavaScript code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>typeof vs instanceof</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">

var myString = "MyString";
alert( typeof myString );
alert( myString instanceof String );

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

The first alert say `string` (in lower case) when the second say `false`...

Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does instanceof return false for some literals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203739/why-does-instanceof-return-false-for-some-literals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the **primitive** type `string` and the type object for your object which is an instance of `String`. They're different.

```
var s = "a"; // a string, typeof is "string"
var s = new String("a"); // an instance of String, typeof is "object"
```

Comment: Thanks! Like in Java between Double and double... But strings in Java are always objets, they are no primitive "string" in Java, even literals.