# instanceof contradicts the object type returned by typeof method

Tags: javascript, arrays

here i have an array of number containing six elements.

```
var arr=[1.22,2.33,2.002,3.992,3.05,5.44];
```

then i store each element inside a variable and tried to find out what type of object it is.i tried both typeof and instanceof .typeof saying that the variable i used to contain the array value is a number but instance of saying that it is not a number.so which one is correct..

then i changed the array a little .used string values instead of number inside the array..

```
var arr=["1.22","2.33","2.002","3.992","3.05","5.44"];
```

here also typeof declaring the values are number type while instanceof saying the opposite.
so can i say it is safe to use **typeof** instead of **instanceof** .so my question is when to use typeof and when to use instanceof and how can i avoid this type of confusion??

***code:***

```
<script>
    function init() {
        var arr = ["1.22", "2.33", "2.002", "3.992", "3.05", "5.44"];
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var bag = arr[i];
            alert(typeof bag == 'string');
            alert(bag instanceof String);
        }
    }
    window.onload = init;
</script>
```

Comment: Your strings are primitives. Changing them to `String("1.22")` will allow instanceof to work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does instanceof return false for some literals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203739/why-does-instanceof-return-false-for-some-literals)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> typeof saying that the variable i used to contain the array value is a number but instance of saying that it is not a number.so which one is correct.

Both. :-)

JavaScript has both *primitive* and *object* versions of numbers, strings, and booleans. `typeof` says `"number"` for *primitive* numbers, which are not objects, and so are not `instanceof Number`.

```
var a = 5;
console.log(typeof a);            // "number"
console.log(a instanceof Number); // false
```

It's ***very rare*** that you'll ever want to explicitly create and keep a reference to an *object* version of a number, string, or boolean.

So why do we have them? So we can seem to have methods on primitives. Let's look at my `a` variable above again, and add another statement to the end:

```
var a = 5;
console.log(typeof a);            // "number"
console.log(a instanceof Number); // false
console.log(a.toFixed(3);         // "5.000"
```

Huh? `a` refers to a primitive number. Primitives don't have methods. So how could I call the `toFixed` method?

The answer is that the JavaScript engine temporarily *promotes* the primitive to the equivalent object type, uses that object type's methods, and throws away the object. (In theory; in practice, of course, engines optimize the process.)

You *can* actually create a `Number` instance:

```
var a = new Number(5);
console.log(typeof a);            // "object"
console.log(a instanceof Number); // true
```

...but again, it's a very, very rare thing to need to do.

Comment: thanks for the explanation.. :)) so can i say instanceof only works when we create objects using new keywords??

Comment: @user3138436: `instanceof` only works with objects (regardless of how they were created). Primitives are not `instanceof` anything (because they're not instances). So it works with `[]` for instance (`[] instanceof Array` will be true), but not with `"foo"` or `true` or `27.4`. :-) This article on my blog might be useful: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/say-what.html

Comment: `So why do we have them?` Because in javascript everything is an object, but primitives are there to make life easy (so `a === 5` rather than `a.valueOf() === 5`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG: :-) Well, of course, everything in JavaScript *isn't* an object -- we have primitives! (Only the four [if you include `undefined`], but...) If everything were an object, what would `valueOf` return? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`instanceof()` better to use when you want to check if that variable is instance of `someClass`.

And `typeof()` better to use when you want get type of variable, not checks from what class this instance was created.

Also, read how instanceof works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) and how works typeof [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

**UPD**: My lovely example for difference between those:

```
var array = [];
typeof array == 'array'; // false
typeof array == 'object'; // true
array instanceof Object; // true
array instanceof Array; // true
```