# In ES6, how do you check the class of an object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In the ES6, if I make a class and create an object of that class, how do I check that the object is that class?

I can't just use `typeof` because the objects are still `"object"`.  Do I just compare constructors?

Example:

```
class Person {
  constructor() {}
}

var person = new Person();

if ( /* what do I put here to check if person is a Person? */ ) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Can't you do `person instanceof Person`?

Comparing constructors alone won't work for subclasses

Comment: Yup, completely forgot about that!  It works just like it would with functions (because the classes are just functions!). Thanks!

Comment: this is not correct answer. if you have A,B,C classes and B & C extends A, then (new B()) instanceof C returns true.

Comment: @someUser: `new B() instanceof A` is the most reasonable definition of inheritance in javascript. If you're finding that you get that for `B` and `C`, then your issue is that you've actually made `B` inherit from `C` when you didn't intend to. How are you implementing your inheritance?

Comment: **Important**: `instanceof` does not do type checking the way that you expect similar checks to do in strongly typed languages. Instead, it does an identity check on the prototype object, and it’s easily fooled. It won’t work across execution contexts, for instance (a common source of bugs, frustration, and unnecessary limitations). For reference, an example in the wild, from bacon.js: https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/issues/296

Comment: @Noah: that sounds more like a warning about execution contexts, as the link discusses. You can construct an equivalent case in C++ with the same problem using `dynamic_cast` and classes within compilation units. So this does behave like strongly-typed languages, even if you don't expect that from them either.

Answer (score 6):

Just a word of caution, the use of `instanceof` seems prone to failure for literals of built-in JS classes (e.g. `String`, `Number`, etc). In these cases it might be safer to use `typeof` as follows:

`typeof("foo") === "string";`

Refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203739/why-does-instanceof-return-false-for-some-literals) for more info.

Comment: You could add double validation

Comment: Wrong answer, don't use this. It will display object for certain objects i.g. console.log(typeof new Array()); // object