# What is a string literal an instanceof?

Tags: javascript, instanceof, string-literals

In JavaScript, is there an instanceof that corresponds to a string literal, such that `'some string' instanceof ___` would return true? **NOTE:** I'm not trying to solve a problem, this is more of a knowledge/curiosity question, wanting to have a little more in-depth knowledge on this particular part of JavaScript.

Comment: A string literal creates a string. Any operands that you try to use with it will operate on that (resulting) string.

Comment: String literal is a source code token, there is no such thing in runtime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does instanceof return false for some literals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203739/why-does-instanceof-return-false-for-some-literals)

Comment: If it's a primitive string, it is not an object, and not an instance of anything.

Comment: One workaround to this could be to initialize a new string via the constructor of 'some string' like this: `new 'some string'.constructor instanceof String //returns true`

Comment: @hackerrdave how is it different from simply `new String()`?

Comment: no different in this case - would be more useful pattern if you weren't certain of the type in a variable, ie: `new myValue.constructor instanceof String`

Comment: @Thilo - that answers my question! Thanks.

Comment: @hackerrdave - I'm not trying to solve anything, so I don't need a workaround - this is purely a knowledge/curiosity question.

Comment: you can use `typeof` and the result would be `'string'`, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var simpleStr = 'This is a simple string'; 
var myString  = new String();
var newStr    = new String('String created with constructor');

simpleStr instanceof String; // returns false
myString  instanceof String; // returns true
newStr    instanceof String; // returns true
myString  instanceof Object; // returns true
```

you can typeof instead of instanceof when you compare strings

```
var simpleStr = 'This is a simple string'; 
typeof simpleStr;//returns string
```

refer to instanceof:
[instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

refer to typeof:
[typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Answer (score -1):

@Thilo answered this in his comment:

> If it's a primitive string, it is not an object, and not an instance of anything.