# Why the return value is false when check the instance of Exception class inherit from Error class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I already read this post: [Why does instanceof return false for some literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203739/why-does-instanceof-return-false-for-some-literals)

But didn't find any information about `Error` object work with `instanceof` operator. Here is my example:

```js
class ErrorType1 extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
  }
}

class ErrorType2 extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
  }
}

function someOperation(data) {
  if (data === 1) {
    throw new ErrorType1('error 1');
  } else if (data === 2) {
    throw new ErrorType2('error 2');
  } else if (data === 0) {
    throw new Error('unknown error');
  }
}

function main(data) {
  try {
    someOperation(data)
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e instanceof ErrorType2)
    if (e instanceof ErrorType1) {
      console.log(11)
      return e
    } else if (e instanceof ErrorType2) {
      console.log(22)
      return e
    }
    console.log(333)
    throw e;
  }
}

main(2)
```

I expected the `e instanceof ErrorType2` expression should return a `true` value. But the stdout give me an `false` value and the `console.log(333)` statement executed. Here is the result:

[image]

Do I missing anything?

**UPDATE**

I used to guess it's my network issue, maybe some static resources don't load. But after I turn on the VPN, the result is same.

Comment: This works as described for me. It outputs `true` followed by `22` which is exactly what I'd expect from your description. (I've executed that code in my browser console, not through the snippet, by the way).

Comment: It looks to be an issue with the version of babel-standalone used by Stack Snippets. The code without Babel runs as expected, as does typing it directly into the [online transpiler](https://babeljs.io/repl)

Comment: @CertainPerformance OK, I was losing my mind here. I copied the snippet and played around with it and nothing about the behaviour made sense. I completely missed that Babel was ticked.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, after I compile my example code, the compiled code works fine. So, is it a bug for SO?

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes, run this example code in the console of chrome 73, it also works fine.

Comment: Babel [just cannot polyfill it](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4485)