# Using instanceof in TypeScript to find return type of function results in "refers to a type, but is being used as a value here"

Tags: typescript

I am using TypeScript and have a situation where a function returns a union of two types. It can either return a string or a model but I don't know how to get the type and perform an action based on what type was returned.

How would I do something like this?
How are string and IMyModel being used as values in this example (as suggested by the error message)? The error seems confusing to me.

```
export interface IMyModel {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const myFunc = (value: boolean): string | IMyModel => {
  if (value) return "a string";

  return {
    id: 12,
    name: "model",
  };
};

const a = myFunc(true);

if (a instanceof string) {
  console.log("it is a string");
}

if (a instanceof IMyModel) {
  console.log("it is a model");
}
```

I get the following static errors in visual studio code on the lines using `instanceof`:

> 'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)
>
> 'IMyModel' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)

[image]

I also switched the interface to use "type" but that's the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is a superset of javascript and ultimately compiles down to javascript. That being said it's important to think about what the code you are writing will look like as javascript. [Here is what this will look like compiled](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQFkBPQiAE2ABs4BvAKDkXIC44kBXAWwCM0BuRu0xdgbAM4woyAOaCAvvXrYISSXC7EAYhyTY4AXjgAKAG6YqHMXB4QIVYJiQBKCVNlwAPgRJlKNAwA%20OiEEdBNzS2BnOChgGA4oJDgAIkw4SWkkGRTBITiEpJCmJgRWOABGACYAGiEmJBFrFK4KahS6pnkFPJU1eHSjTR09YykrZzywk3TkSSdcCHDM2RiGJj7xe2AAOioIGWMUhHgEcTh0leyUyfpFemnjWf6F4CWfUjaqNaFN7b2DkcTohzulWv4bgogA):

```
const myFunc = value => {
  if (value) return "a string";
  return {
    id: 12,
    name: "model"
  };
};
const a = myFunc(true);
if (a instanceof string) {
  console.log("it is a string");
}
if (a instanceof IMyModel) {
  console.log("it is a model");
}
```

You'll notice that the types you declared are compiled away. The error is starting to make a bit more sense now. We can't call `instanceof` on a typescript type because they don't exist as far as the compiled javascript is concerned. You are probably looking for either:

[`typeof` type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards)

```
if (typeof a === 'string') {
  console.log("it is a string");
}
```

[User defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
const isMyModel = (model: any): model is IMyModel => {
  return typeof model === 'object' && Boolean(model.id && model.name)
}
if (isMyModel(a)) {
  console.log("it is a model");
}
```

or both!

Comment: `a instanceof String` won't work. `'foo' instanceof String` is `false`

Comment: Can we actually ever use `instanceof` in plain old JS to check for types? I'm not sure why 'foo' instanceof String fails.

Comment: One of the best javascript SO quotes from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/203757/7165303

"An easy way to remember things like this is asking yourself "I wonder what would be sane and easy to learn"? Whatever the answer is, Javascript does the other thing."

Answer (score 1):

To check if something is a string you would do it the same way as in JavaScript

```
if (typeof a === "string")
```

Interfaces are purely a TypeScript construct and to not exist in the transpiled JavaScript. Since it is a union you can make the assumption that if it is not a string it must be an `IMyModel`.

Answer (score 1):

Right-hand parameter in `object instanceof constructor` expression should be constructor/function.

> The `instanceof` operator tests the presence of `constructor.prototype` in `object`'s prototype chain.

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

---

Back to your example. One of the possible solutions will be testing if [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) `a` is a `'string'`:

```
if (typeof a === 'string') {
  a // a is of type string here
  console.log("it is a string");
} else {
  a // a is IModel
  console.log("it is a model");
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQFkBPQiAE2ABs4BvAKDkXIC44kBXAWwCM0BuRu0xdgbAM4woyAOaCAvvXrYISSXC7EAYhyTY4AXjgAKAG6YqHMXB4QIVYJiQBKCVNlwAPgRJlKNAwA+OiEEdBNzS2BnOChgGA4oJDgAIkw4SWkkGRTBITiEpJCmJgRWOABGACYAGiEmJBFrFK4KahS6pnkFPJU1eHSjTR09YykrZzywkxhiMGAIcMGDIwByTNlVmIYmdIB6Pbh0hHE4RbhZ+Yz3bLgACzRgIT7xe2AAOioIGWMUhHgTkdrlkcpN6PI4NRxHgdkCDkDAUQ2lRnqpXg5Pt9fv9EKd0q1-CkwfIgA)

[More](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards) on typeof type guards