# Can assert a variable to be an instance of a String in Deno

Tags: typescript, testing, tdd, deno, type-systems

Can't seem to be able to assert instances of `string` in Deno:

```js
import {
  assertInstanceOf
} from "https://deno.land/std@0.174.0/testing/asserts.ts";

assertInstanceOf( "foo", string );
```

Throws:

```
error: TS2693 [ERROR]: 'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
assertInstanceOf( "foo", string );
                         ~~~~~~
    at file:///home/jmerelo/Code/my-stackoverflow-examples/js/string-assert.ts:6:26
```

Fair enough, let's try this

```js
assertInstanceOf( "foo", String );
```

Now I'm confused:

```
Uncaught error from ./string-assert.ts FAILED

 ERRORS 

./string-assert.ts (uncaught error)
error: AssertionError: Expected object to be an instance of "String" but was "string".
```

Any idea of what would be the correct type here?

There's clearly a workaround here, to use `typeof`. But I would like to know what's the solution to this Catch-22

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"string"` the *string* with content "string"? The `string` identifier all lowercase shouldn't refer to anything at runtime. Unless there is something in the setup that makes the ambient context available at runtime? `String` in uppercase would refer to the string *constructor*. And primitive strings aren't instances of it: `"hello" instanceof String` is `false`.

Comment: Checking [the documentation](https://deno.land/manual@v1.30.0/basics/testing/assertions#instance-types) it doesn't say you can assert primitives. It very explicitly states "*To check if an object is an instance of a specific constructor*" which, again, primitives aren't instances of a constructor. Clearly doesn't do TS type-level checking at runtime.

Comment: @VLAZ so I guess it's the workaround, right?

Comment: The documentation also shows you can create your own asserters. So you can probably just make one for primitive types.

Comment: Related: [Why does instanceof return false for some literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/203739)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There's clearly a workaround here, to use `typeof`. But I would like to know what's the solution to this Catch-22

It's not a [Catch-22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(logic)), but a [false premise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_premise). In JavaScript: while [primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) do appear [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Object)-like in some aspects, they are not objects (see [JavaScript data types and data structures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)) — therefore they are not useful operands for use with the [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator because the evaluation will always be `false` (see [spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-instanceofoperator)):

> **`instanceof`**
>
> The instanceof operator tests to see if the prototype property of a constructor appears anywhere in the prototype chain of an **object**.

For strings, this is explained further on MDN's `String` article in the section [String primitives and String objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#string_primitives_and_string_objects).

Below is a code example demonstrating how to discriminate and assert whether a value is a string literal or an object instance of [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) using [Deno's standard testing library](https://deno.land/std/testing) and user-defined [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) functions.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PTAEEsFsAcHsCcAuoDeoCGBnTBTJoBfUAM3lklACIALRRaTALhABMcA7WAOgBt12WwTIhYABAAxcAjAHYArF3HBEOYeHYBzYFlxJMXRJkoBuAFCmQoALQ2AfKABCODeojse6nCwgwEh85a09EysHNx8AkIiEtLyisqqiOpaOniGBpgA-JiwAK7wAMY4AMQAMlIAnKYFfNigAILYaeCw7ACi8GTwoDgAHioCmKAdXaimoKCwAG548OBsoOzokDigALxUjbpJrSMIJuOgBa3C8LkFiAgAFCvY6Bo4jKCnyQCUYxMTmLnQeDeqmHuOFeZgmBFM4IsYCCDGYwDYnF4-EEwjEklkCiUKjUmm0TT0GWyeUKJXKAGYABwWABU1NAAFl0ABrVb8DD4nbsAA0PU6CFAAHdwDweKAAEarRDUMgC9gQYigAAGfWg8EVoBYsFUi1gyGo6BmoEQZylAE9QFN0DxcjguKBqcBTMRcuwLi05akkFcVfAni6mZxZTzIJgNOsqJRXk9PYYer1VR95aArgBCH3vFCHCZSmWLHAChoc917eA3UMgw7gyGWAA8NiswwEbg87C8PjgenMztdnIgmAAysbkqVwCp4FarugLrkrX72AHYLKoxhp1a+88h5pE-AcIh8nLEKbfrAFVO92u1peqC9NAdId23a0+4O5poAJLsYT8IqT1c8OcLku0Z-uuL7JNuu77kaR44CeK7nqKl4bJQsBigAVjgFyUKAABkOHwTOorqF+rqwQqYGaGY94uo+crgJg9TsKaFEaL+CEAYG7DLmehHrjeYYAD6gCxEF7vAdEDpuGgjmOE48Va7wCUJ9EsR+JE-vJPAVpCxyfsg2KIAAwlgqhPAA2ksKxPPxPKWtajygP6nEALpmc54ZmYcZmUPxoAeLJPCUDylDELAsCUM5XJeT5UluOpOBBXmBYsVcIVhZGkXRewuSQBK3T+XgVqJQALAATJlEzedluV4HFiDfglPKtgWAByOV5VcZWvJlzlmNUJywDwto8LArGUAAKok4Ghd0vmHr8+hcFwkZ9TNya6cIoAWcsOC2VaNruXBBnGbgmAZocxrmpmnzstsVz0YxzFSVcdk2q8FY3Rtg3DaNqWAKDkiWWcCoKEEc6CIAU1CJhMX1DVwszXJQgAy5IDO0fZ8ulJNlOAg5C2bwFdWa3Wk92Sa+0mjoVPAvftwLozDA1wyNY3zY8iWUAV46BejRAFODkPQ8TXoqVJan1aRNP2e9IMM5+328L9lCs4w7PEeLRQrZWEKmEAA)

`module.ts`:

```ts
import { assert } from "https://deno.land/std@0.175.0/testing/asserts.ts";

function isStringLiteral(actual: unknown): actual is string {
  return typeof actual === "string";
}

function isStringInstance(actual: unknown): actual is String {
  return typeof actual === "object" && actual instanceof String;
}

function isAnyString(actual: unknown): actual is string | String {
  return isStringLiteral(actual) || isStringInstance(actual);
}

const testCases: [name: string, value: unknown][] = [
  ["string literal", "foo"],
  ["string instance", new String("foo")],
  ["number literal", 42],
  ["number instance", new Number(42)],
];

console.log("Testing for string types...");

for (const [name, value] of testCases) {
  try {
    assert(isAnyString(value));
    console.log("✅", name);
  } catch {
    console.error("❌", name);
    continue;
  }

  try {
    assert(isStringLiteral(value));
    console.log("type:", "literal");
  } catch {
    assert(isStringInstance(value));
    console.log("type:", "instance");
  }
}
```

Output:

```txt
% deno --version
deno 1.30.0 (release, x86_64-apple-darwin)
v8 10.9.194.5
typescript 4.9.4

% deno check module.ts

% echo $?
0

% deno run module.ts
Testing for string types...
✅ string literal
type: literal
✅ string instance
type: instance
❌ number literal
❌ number instance
```

Compiled JavaScript with imports inlined:

```js
// import { assert } from "https://deno.land/std@0.175.0/testing/asserts.ts";

// ---> Begin inlined imports

// https://deno.land/std@0.175.0/testing/asserts.ts?source#L19
class AssertionError extends Error {
  name = "AssertionError";
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
  }
}

// https://deno.land/std@0.175.0/testing/asserts.ts?source#L138
/** Make an assertion, error will be thrown if `expr` does not have truthy value. */
function assert(expr, msg = "") {
  if (!expr) {
    throw new AssertionError(msg);
  }
}

// <--- End inlined imports

function isStringLiteral(actual) {
  return typeof actual === "string";
}
function isStringInstance(actual) {
  return typeof actual === "object" && actual instanceof String;
}
function isAnyString(actual) {
  return isStringLiteral(actual) || isStringInstance(actual);
}
const testCases = [["string literal", "foo"], ["string instance", new String("foo")], ["number literal", 42], ["number instance", new Number(42)]];
console.log("Testing for string types...");
for (const [name, value] of testCases) {
  try {
    assert(isAnyString(value));
    console.log("✅", name);
  } catch {
    console.error("❌", name);
    continue;
  }
  try {
    assert(isStringLiteral(value));
    console.log("type:", "literal");
  } catch {
    assert(isStringInstance(value));
    console.log("type:", "instance");
  }
}
```